# Comparing Multiple Tables

Tags: c#, sqlite, datatable

There is a horrible legacy tool at my workplace that has been updated/patched to output information to an SQLite database. No one wants to touch the back end of the system, and I don't know enough to dig into it - not my problem. Here is my problem however:

I have an SQLite database, with a number of tables in it. Each table represents a day and contains all of the bus runs, listed such as such:

```
| Direction |   Time   | RunNumber | StopIndex |
 ----------------------------------------------
|    In     |   6:30   |     1     |     1     |
|    In     |   6:35   |     1     |     2     |
|    In     |   6:40   |     1     |     3     |
|    In     |   6:45   |     1     |     4     |
|    In     |   7:30   |     2     |     1     |
|    In     |   7:35   |     2     |     2     |
|    In     |   7:40   |     2     |     3     |
|    In     |   7:45   |     2     |     4     |
|    Out    |   6:40   |     1     |     1     |
|    Out    |   6:45   |     1     |     2     |
|    Out    |   6:50   |     1     |     3     |
|    Out    |   6:55   |     1     |     4     |
```

Some days can have more run's than others. The numbers of stops will be the same across all tables.

The definition of equal is that both direction and time are the same. Each run is treated as a set - if one of the times for a stop differs, then the entire run needs to be merged into a table.

My question is:

What would be the easiest way, given a list of tables, to generate another table that contains values that were not present on all the given tables? This can be done on the SQLite side, or by C# .NET 4.0.

In reality, I only need to know the run number that differs, so I can later extract it and put it into an Excel Spreadsheet, if that makes it any easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try using EXCEPT. For example, the following query will list all rows that exist in Table1 but do not exist in Table2:

```
SELECT Direction, Time, RunNumber, StopIndex
FROM Table1
EXCEPT
SELECT Direction, Time, RunNumber, StopIndex
FROM Table2
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this on a less selective criteria?

My problem is that anywhere in the table, another trip may be inserted, which then causes the RunNumber to be n + 1 for every subsequent trip. Using this method causes every row after the addition to be returned, as the RunNumber is n + 1 (Or however many runs were inserted).